# At which order Interface Builder evaluates IBInspectables?

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I have custom UI element designed with a help of `IBInspectables`, so that I can use and modify it in the Interface Builder. There are 2 inspectables which effectively change the same property of the element but in a slightly different manner.

[image]

At the screenshot there is `title` that sets the title of the element, and `locTitleKey` that gets `NSLocalizedString` by the key and sets it as the title.

As I can see from passing different values to these inspectables:

1. If `locTitleKey` is specified, and `title` is left empty, the localised string is used
2. If both are specified, `title` is used and localized one is ignored

**The question - is that behaviour predictable?**

In other words, can I safely assume that the order of evaluation of my `IBInspectables` always be the same? (`title` and then `locTitleKey`)

To provide more context here are the snippets of code used.

`title` is defined in the scope of the class itself:

```
@IBDesignable
class StandardInputField: UIView, NibLoadable {
    //...
    @IBInspectable
    public var title: String? {
        didSet {
            titleLabel.text = title
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

And `locTitleKey` is defined as extension:

```
extension StandardInputField {
    @IBInspectable var locTitleKey: String? {
        get {
            return nil
        }
        set(key) {
            title = key?.localized
        }
    }
}
```